# How type declarations in brackets work in Haskell like (Integer -> Integer) -> Integer

Tags: haskell, types, type-systems

I am a beginner at Haskell and programming. I am learning how to write functions based on type declarations.How to write function which types are declared in brackets like (a -> b) -> b.

When I tried this:

```
z :: (Integer -> Integer) -> Integer
z x y = x + y
```

I got an error like this:

```
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Integer’
                  with actual type ‘(Integer -> Integer) -> Integer -> Integer’
    • The equation(s) for ‘z’ have two arguments,
      but its type ‘(Integer -> Integer) -> Integer’ has only one
```

If I give only one parameter assigned to the integer, it does type check,

```
z f = 9
```

but no idea how to use that function as it show an error when i type z 9:

```
  • No instance for (Num (Integer -> Integer))
        arising from the literal ‘5’
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    • In the first argument of ‘z’, namely ‘5’
      In the expression: z 5
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = z 5
```

**How to write proper functions for such type declarations and how do they work?**

Comment: Your `z` expects the parameter to be a *function*. So Your implementation of `z` does not make much sense, since you here take *two* parameters, and since the first one is a function, if you implement this with `x + y`, it expects that you can add two functions together.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem,Thanks for the reply.So instead of assigning Integer , do i need to assign function such that the function returns integer?

Comment: Might be helpful, another example of a function of signature `z :: (Integer -> Integer) -> Integer` is `z f = f 42`.  `z` is a function that takes another function as its argument, which will be applied to 42. So `z negate = -42`, `z (+1) = 43`, and `z (*2) = 84`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```hs
z :: (a -> b) -> c
```

is the signature of a function that takes a `a -> b` and returns a `c`; and `a -> b` is in turn a function that takes a `a` and returns a `b`.

The definition

```hs
z x y = x + y
```

is incompatible with that type. This latter function, indeed, has signature

```hs
z :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

which you can think of as the same as the following

```hs
z :: a -> b -> c
```

where the use of `+` in the definition has the effect of requiring that

- `a` be a `Num`,
- and `b` and `c` be the same as `a`.

When you write

```hs
z :: (Integer -> Integer) -> Integer
z f = 9
```

you are defining a function `z` which takes a function `Integer -> Integer`, doesn't use it at all, and returns `9` regardless.

So you could call `z (+3)`, i.e. passing the function "plus 3" to `z`, and you would get out `9`.

In fact, you'll get `9` whenever you feed `z` with something that can be seen as `Integer -> Integer`. This is obviously true for `z (+3)`, `z (subtract 9)`, and so on, but it's also true for `z undefined`, because `undefined` has type `undefined :: a`, i.e. it can take the place of any type, including `Integer -> Integer`.